# PHP Seconds Difference time() PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

Hi I'm trying to to do the following with php and html:
I have a form that submits time() and stores it as the variable `TIMESTAMP` in `$POST`, the next time the form is submitted a new variable is posted called `DELAY`, which is time()-`TIMESTAMP`. The process seems to work, but my problem appears to the PHP time() function seems to be a bit fluttery.

I can submit the form every lets say 3 secs and sometimes `DELAY` = 3 as it should other times its not correct like say 7 secs or even 12 secs. How can I get the `time()` function to be more accurate when returning the current time?

I need to use the delay in an MySQL query that is only executed when the delay is greater than 15 secs

Comment: I've never seen `time()` behave *fluttery*. Have you accounted for network overhead?

Comment: How exactly are you ensuring that the function is called exactly every 3 seconds?

Comment: Do you reset you TIMESTAMP after each submit? I mean, if you don't, the second delay will be calcultaed between now and the first timestamp, wich could get you a 7sec then 12sec delay

Answer (score 0):

This is surely not php time() related.

If you're running on a virtual machine, you can experience time drifts if host is not configured properly. Check if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code help you

```
function DifTime($T1,$T2){
         $diff=abs($T2-$T1);
         $years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
         $months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
         $days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
         $hours   = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60)); 
         $minuts  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60); 
         $seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60)); 
         return array('Day'=>$days,'Month'=>$months,'Year'=>$years,'Hours'=>$hours,'Minuts'=>$minuts,'Seconds'=>$seconds);
     }
```

sample:

```
  $Data=DifTime(TIMESTAMP,(time()-TIMESTAMP)+TIMESTAMP);
  printf("%d:%d:%d:%d", $Data['Day'], $Data['Hours'], $Data['Minuts'], $Data['Seconds']);
```

output:

```
0:0:0:10
```